# D3 contourDensity - problem with projection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

Im am trying to draw a contour density map using [d3-contour](https://github.com/d3/d3-contour) I have been following this example so far: [d3 Density Contour example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/density-contours)

I have an array of coordinates representing several points that get very dense.
[picture of map with points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWJ9T.png), I have been trying to use `d3.contourDensity()` to generate MultiPolygons and then using `d3.geoPath()` plot them on the map. The process works quite smoothly until I try to project the geometries resulting from the contour density generator:

```
projection = d3.geoEqualEarth().scale(190).translate([this.svgWidth / 2, this.svgHeight / 2]).precision(0.1)

path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection)


 // Here I create my contourDensity generator
  const contourGenerator = d3.contourDensity()
                                 .x(d => d.longitude)
                                 .y(d => d.latitude)
                                 .size([width, height])
                                 .bandwidth(30)
                                 .thresholds(30)

// Here is where I input the data (* - see below)
const contours = contourGenerator(entries)

// Here I loop over the resulting Polygons to project them

const paths = contours.map(c => {
  return path(c)
})
```

The thing is: I manage to plot *something* but it's an absolutely random mass of shapes that don't really make that much sense.
[The messy result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu7pb.jpg)
My sense is that I am either misinterpreting the way `d3.contourDensity()` works or I am messing up with the projection, however I tried everything I could and I still can't understand what's the problem, please help!

(*) My data look like this:

```
entries = [...,{
       longitude: -119.2717761, 
       latitude: 35.5005139, 
       comment: "I am a comment, I am useless"
    }]
```

Comment: As d3-contour considers planar coordinates, and you have 3D coordinates (lat long pairs), you might be better to feed the projected points to d3-contour rather than the raw coordinates. Depending on projection selection and area of interest, this could be more accurate than projecting the lat/long pairs, but will also contemplate the where the points will be drawn as opposed to where the points would be if using a plate carree (ie when using lat long as Cartesian data with no transform). This latter point I believe is the likely source of your issues. I can expand in an answer if needed.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. If I understand what you mean I'll need to project the points within the `contourGenerator` function and then use `geoPath()` without projection, right?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't, they are positioned outside the svg viewbox.

Comment: Hmm, I'll take a closer look tonight, but if you could share any additional detail/code that might be useful.

Comment: I put together a tiny codesandbox example reproducing the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/map-contour-7kbbr?file=/src/components/Map.vue

Comment: You mixed the order of lat/long for the y accessor of d3-contour. also projection returns an array, [x,y], you need to separate x,y coordinates: `this.projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0]`, [eg](https://codesandbox.io/s/map-contour-forked-xvl5d?file=/src/components/Map.vue), otherwise you were there.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you very much!